# How can I split the characters(all locales) and numbers from a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Note: I am using `Intl.DateTimeFormat` to format the date and time, but the problem there is I could't get the meridian value alone (for the given date) by using that API. But I can get the meridian value (for the specified date) with the time string like below,

-> 下午4:38

-> 4.58 AM

...so, I need to write two methods to get the meridian and time value from that strings.

For example,

`getMeridian('下午4:38')` -> `下午`

`getMeridian('4.58 AM')`  -> `AM`

`getTimeWithoutMeridian('下午4:38')` -> `4:58`

`getTimeWithoutMeridian('4.58 AM')`  -> `4.58`

Can anyone help me on this issue? Thanks!

Comment: How do you know that for a particular "locale" the am/pm designator is used? Surely it's best to just look at the hours: if >=12, it's PM, otherwise AM (noting that 12 PM is a *non sequitur*).

Comment: @RobG, thanks for your reply. As you mentioned I can simply check  `if >=12`, but I want the localized merdian string for (any) locales and thats why I am using `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have getTimeWithoutMeridian, why not just do it like this:

```
var getMeridian = function(myString) { myString.replace(getTimeWithoutMeridian(myString), "") }
```

Which is just gonna remove the time string and leave the meridian

Comment: Thanks @Titus. It will work If I find `getTimeWithoutMeridian()`. But (as @RubG mentioned in my answer) I have a problem with Arabic kind of locales. So I am looking for the alternative solution for that.

Answer (score -1):

Below regex helps me to get the `getTimeWithoutMeridian()`.

```
string.replace(/[^0-9:.]+/g, '')
```

Example,

var string = '下午4:38';
string.replace(/[^0-9:.]+/g, '');
O/P: 4:58.

I am still looking the answer for `getMeridian('下午4:38')` -> `下午`

Comment: That only works if the **language** uses characters 0-9. Try with Arabic: "ar-EG" (or any other language that doesn't use ASCII numbers or so–called "Arabic" digits).

Comment: @RobG: thanks again, I am passing a 'optional' params to Intl.DateFormatter which helps to give the numeric values for all locales!

Comment: Arabic returns something like: " ١١:٤٤:٠٧ م" for 11:44:57 PM even if "numeric" or "2-digit" is specified in the options.

Comment: Yes @RobG, you are correct! I am thinking alternate solution for that. In the meantime if you find  anything please share with me.

Comment: It seems to be something of a bug in the specification that you can't get just the am/pm symbol, nor specify common Arabic digits (as opposed to real Arabic numbers, which can be specified by -u-nu-arab or arabtext).